# Neo4J with small graph uses a lot of memory on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, neo4j-bolt

I have installed Neo4J v3.3.0 (community edition) in an Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine (Hyper-V) with 8GB and 4 cores.

I have a very small graph (30 nodes) and it is used just for reading (about 1 hit every 3 seconds), it seldomly gets written to. We want to expand the graph a lot more but every three days (sometimes less) our server crashes because Java is taking more than 2GB and top showed 300% CPU usage.

To me this makes no sense at all, could you please let me know how to configure Java or Neo4J in order to prevent this?

Thanks

I have the following configuration in my `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf` file:

```
dbms.query_cache_size=5000
dbms.threads.worker_count=4
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=2g
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=2g

dbms.memory.pagecache.size=2g
```

The log files show the following error when this happens:

```
ERROR [o.n.b.v.r.c.RunnableBoltWorker] Worker for session 'ecfe4a7f-1714-4ba3-9e98-a692bf153b45' crashed. Java heap space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

There are also these suspicious messages (which there are a lot of):

```
WARN [o.n.k.i.c.MonitorGc] GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 4680ms.

ERROR [o.n.b.v.t.BoltMessagingProtocolV1Handler] Failed to write response to driver Unable to write to the closed output channel org.neo4j.bolt.v1.packstream.PackOutputClosedException: Unable to write to the closed output channel

WARN [io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline] An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception. syscall:read(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
```

**New Information**

I did an:

```
netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED
```

I had a lot of open connections. We are using the following javascript driver in nodeJS (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver). Will check if we are not properly checking connections.

It seems I am closing correctly all connections properly with:

```
session.close();
driver.close();
```

The connections still remain open until I exit the application.

**Final Comments**

There was a place in my code where I was not closing connections.

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/issues/275

Answer (score 2):

I can say, that Neo4j works fine for me on 8GB of RAM with 10mln nodes and 30mln relations without special tuning.

top shows 300% CPU usage probably when garbage collection is done. So I vote for **increasing** heap size

```
/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf
```

parameter

```
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=3g
```

On larger databases high CPU consumption mean absence of indexes.

To list indexes:

```
CALL db.indexes();
```

to create one:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Label(prop_name);
```

If you get OOM errors (see dmesg) and java gets killed by linux (not crashes), try to install server OS, like **CentOS** without GUI et c, to free some memory. 8GB is more than enough for Neo4j with 8-10GB size database.

Comment: I updated my question with my current neo4j.conf, I already have heap size equal to 2g. It's conforting to know you have a lot more nodes and Neo4J runs fine. I am still confused why it consumes so many resources in my configuration with such a small graph.

Comment: You haven't said if JVM gets killed by OOM-killer or it crashes itself after failing to free internal JVM memory. That's crucial. Also post your dbms.memory.pagecache.size setting it is by default set for half of total RAM.

Comment: Also check your queries. As far as I know neo4j doesn't have timeout setting for long queries, so after 3 days it might be executing hundreds simultaneously.

Comment: How can I check how many queries arebeing executed simultaneously? Our queries are very simple shoudln´t be long runnign queries.